# Three permutations

Tags: mathematics

Let A=(1,2,3,4,5) be a list of numbers. We can permute this list (change order of elements) to get lists B and C. The similarity of two lists is the number of elements that have the same value and location. My friend claims that he can find three such lists A, B and C with 5 elements as above, such that the similarity of A and B is 2, A and C is 2, B and C is 3. Is my friend telling the truth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your friend is

> Telling a lie

Reasoning

> A is an [even permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation) of the set B (since it involves disordering of three of the elements).
>  C is an even permutation of A (same reason).
>  The composition of two even permutations is even which would make C an even permutation of B (if we permute via A).
>  However, C and B differ by only a swap of two elements which is an odd permutation, a contradiction.

Comment: You are correct and very fast!

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Thanks, good question.

Answer (score 2):

A less elegant answer:

> Symmetry means we might as well let: 
>  B=(1,2,3,4,5) 
>  C=(1,2,3,5,4) 
>  It's worth noting that A is just as similar to B as it is to C. The sub-similarity for the first three numbers is equal because both C and B's are 1, 2 and 3, so same for the last two (A vs. 4,5 and A vs 5,4), but the only way for the second sub-similarity to satisfy that is A having two numbers different from 4 or 5 as the last two terms. Let A=(X,Y,Z,1,2), but then it won't allow its similarity be 2, ever. Your friend lied.